# Braintree - How to retry a soft declined transaction via API?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing, braintree

Is it possible to retry a soft declined transaction via Braintree API?

Comment: I work at Braintree. I suggest you [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted Braintree support and got useful info. Basically, we can retry a soft declined transaction via creating a new transaction with the declined amount against the saved payment method token of the customer.